# Python / Import module pymssql / from Linux to Windows

Tags: python, pymssql

I have a python script running on linux, with this declaration :

```
import _mssql
```

In the library listed there is pymssql (I can't find other relative library)

I am trying to adapt this code to windows, so I have installed pymssql but when I try to declare it like in the linux version, I have this message :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_mssql'

What could be the cause ? Why using an underscore to import this library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes obviously the correct syntax is :

```
import pymssql._mssql
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you should be importing it. Please read their documentation: https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html